# Упростить код JS

Tags: javascript

```
try {

} catch(e) {

    FormData.prototype.appendAll = function(obj) {
         for (let key in obj)
             this.append(key, obj[key]);
         return this;
     };

     fetch('/ajax/', {method: 'POST', body: new FormData().appendAll({md:'core', po:'javascript', text:e})}).then(rsp => console.log(e));

}
```

Возможно ли писать как то иначе, дабы не прописывать

```
FormData.prototype.appendAll
```

И в тоже время чтобы громоздко не было... Необходимо всего навсего, отправить сообщение об обшибке с дальнейшей ее записью в файл.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: не добавляй в прототип - используй обычную функцию. Встроенных методов для добавления нескольких значений - нет. Максимум можно передать в конструктор элемент формы.

Comment: method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify({md:'core', po:'javascript', text:e})}

Comment: Не выходит.......

Comment: Заголовок нужно добавить `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`. Но это не решение, если Вы не ожидаете получить JSON на сервере. Если требуется именно `multipart/form-data`, то как выше отмечено, лучше создать одну функцию и использовать ее где требуется.

Comment: а в чем проблема вынести кусок кода, как функция-хелпер, потом юзать где нужно? Я думаю она не одна такая будет